# Creating a Cocoa file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a Cocoa file with a subclass of UITableViewCell so I could have an outlet to a prototype cell. Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with the titles for all your labels. For instance:

```
var titleLabels: [String] = ["Eggs", "Cheese", "Milk"]
```

Load your custom cell class (put this in viewDidLoad):

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "YourCellSubclass", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Then implement cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.detailLabel?.text = self.titleLabels[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

(Make sure you remember to set this class as the datasource for your tableview).

To include the quantities on the cells, you'll need another array of numbers (or better yet, an array of objects, each with a name and quantity attribute). Then (assuming your cell has two labels - one for the title, one for the quantity) you can set both the titleLabel and quantityLabel on your cell in the same manner as shown above.

This article has a pretty good walkthrough on creating custom tableview cells: https://www.weheartswift.com/swifting-around/

Comment: Import your cell's header file into your controller, then you can replace the 'UITableViewCell' with 'YourCellSubclass' in the cell declaration above so you can access your outlets.

Comment: By 'YourCellSubclass' I meant the name of the cell class you created. (The one that's subclassing UITableViewCell).

Comment: How do I import the file?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you the lines to load the cell's nib file. I also added a link to a full walkthrough that will probably be more useful to you than a short answer post.

Comment: When I run this I get an error of 'UITableViewCell' does not have a member named "detailLabel" ' Why is this? I also get an error of ' Cannot dequeue resusable cell with identifier with an argument list of type '(String)' '. Please help me out!

Comment: Probably because you don't have a 'detailLabel' outlet defined (that was just an example name I used). If you are using just the standard UITableviewCell, you can set the text using the built-in 'textLabel' outlet. When you set the text on your custom cell, you'll need to use whatever outlet you created.  This comment thread is getting a bit long, so if you have further questions, consider opening a new question post so you can show the code you've got so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the custom UITableViewCell with two `UILabel`s, for example `titleLabel` and `detailLabel`. In the custom `initWithStyle` method, you can set the desired position of the labels within the cell.

After initializing the custom cell, you could write another method in the custom `UITableViewCell` class that sets the text values of `titleLabel` and `detailLabel`, and call that method from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The desired values could come from an `NSArray`, and you would use the cell row, `indexPath.row`, to fetch the corresponding values from the array.